# python generator: unpack entire generator in parallel

Tags: python, parallel-processing, generator

Suppose I have a generator whose `__next__()` function is somewhat expensive and I want to try to parallelize the calls. Where do I throw in the parallization?

To be slightly more concrete, consider this example:

```
# fast, splitting a file for example
raw_blocks = (b for b in block_generator(fin))
# slow, reading blocks, checking values ...
parsed_blocks = (block_parser(b) for b in raw_blocks)
# get all parsed blocks into a data structure
data = parsedBlocksToOrderedDict(parsed_blocks)
```

The most basic thing is to change the 2nd line to something that does the parallelization. Is there some generator magic that allows one to unpack the generator (on the 3rd) line in parallel? Calling `__next__()` in parallel?

Comment: Generally, I would refrain from this. The guts of the interal may be very stateful and thread-unsafe. Consider improving the generator itself instead (assuming it's not just a simple generator expression, but even then you need some thread safety in the involved code to do this).

Comment: I think you've mentioned the solution in your answer. Parallelize the calls to `block_parser`.

Comment: You may want to split you generator into multiple ones (if possible). Starting each one on a pre-calculated stating point. This way you might have a better performance.

Comment: I'm currently working on this. I have a generator that sends HTTP requests or process images in `__next__()`. What I did is to decouple the codes in `__next__()` into two parts: The first part generates something like metadata, e.g., image filename, and the second part does the expensive things. I implemented a wrapper that takes in a cheap generator and a decoding function which does the heavy single process task. It parallelizes the tasks by creating a worker pool and keeps submitting tasks to it. Feel free to use my code but do not use the version on pip, it's extremely unstable, and may so

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. You must call `next()` sequentially because any non-trivial generator's next state is determined by its current state.

```
def gen(num):
    j=0
    for i in xrange(num):
        j += i
        yield j
```

There's no way to parallelize calls to the above generator without knowing its state at each point it yields a value. But if you knew that, you wouldn't need to run it.

Comment: Thanks ... that's what I had guessed but wasn't sure if there was a way to do something with "trivial" generators i.e. "stationary" generators that do not have truly dependent __next__().

Comment: Trivial ones that iterate over a list could be parallelizable (really, you'd break up the list and have a thread iterate over each piece) *but* those are not the kind of generators that take so much time you'd want to parallelize them.

Comment: Trivial here means independent, not 'fast'. Maybe the trick is just not use generators since I do not need or want the concept of a 'state' ... I just need an index to jobs and args.

Comment: By "trivial" I really meant a generator that always yields the same value and doesn't maintain any state whatsoever.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming the calls to `block_parser(b)` to be performed in parallel, you could try using a [multiprocessing.Pool](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool):

```
import multiprocessing as mp

pool = mp.Pool()

raw_blocks = block_generator(fin)
parsed_blocks = pool.imap(block_parser, raw_blocks)
data = parsedBlocksToOrderedDict(parsed_blocks)
```

Note that:

- If you expect that `list(parsed_blocks)` can fit entirely in memory,
  then using `pool.map` can be much faster than `pool.imap`.
- The items in `raw_blocks` and the return values from `block_parse`
  must be pickable since `mp.Pool` transfers tasks and results through
  a `mp.Queue`.

Comment: Yeah, I will use mp.Pool for sure. I will mark the other answer as "correct" since it answers the conceptual question I was asking about generators but this is a good solution you provided.

Comment: isn't `raw_blocks` here the same generator here as `block_generator(fin)`? what is the advantage of creating this new additional but equal generator?

Comment: @MaxPower: Thanks for the improvement. There is no need for the generator expression here.

Comment: @unutbu and how things like `parsedBlocksToOrderedDict` should be done. I mean converting a for loop to a dict ?