# Parallelizing or otherwise speeding up calculation within generator and pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, cython

I am doing a calculation on permutations of things from a generator created by itertools. I have a piece of code in this form (this is a dummy example):

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

combos = itertools.permutations('abcdefghi',2)
results = []
i=0

for combo in combos:
    i+=1 #this line is actually other stuff that's expensive
    results.append([combo[0]+'-'+combo[1],i])

rdf = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['combo','value'])
```

Except in the real code,

- there are several hundred thousand permutations
- instead of `i+=1` I am opening files and getting results of `clf.predict` where `clf` is a classifier trained in scikit-learn
- in place of `i` I'm storing a value from that prediction

I think the `combo[0]+'-'+combo[1]` is trivial though.

This takes too long. What should I do to make it faster? Such as:

1) writing better code (maybe I should initialize `results` with the proper length instead of using `append` but how much will that help? and what's the best way to do that when I don't know the length before iterating through `combs`?)

2) initializing a pandas dataframe instead of a list and using `apply`?

3) using [cython](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html) in pandas? Total newbie to this.

4) [parallelizing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)? I think I probably need to do this, but again, total newbie, and I don't know whether it's better to do it within a list or a pandas dataframe. I understand I would need to iterate over the generator and initialize some kind of container [before parallelizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7972295/python-generator-unpack-entire-generator-in-parallel).

Which combination of these options would be best and how can I put it together?

Comment: `rdf = pd.DataFrame(itertools.permutations('abcdefghi',2), columns=['combo','value'])` best I can think of.

Comment: Actually, that doesn't join the strings. I suspect that's the bottleneck. `i` is superfluous, you could use `enumerate`

Comment: No that's the thing, the i+=1 is just a dummy example. In reality, what's there is very expensive. In place of i+=1, I'm opening files from the names in the permutation, reading them in as dataframes, running clf.predict from a classifier trained in sci-kit learn and storing a value from the prediction. That can't really change so I need to make everything else faster and/or parallelize

Comment: @roganjosh I edited the question to try to make this clearer

Comment: "maybe I should initialize results with the proper length instead of using append but how much will that help?" No help at all.

Comment: " I am opening files and getting results of clf.predict" that is almost certainly the bottleneck. How many classifiers are you working with? A dozen? Hundreds? Thousands? I am guessing they are pickled in some way?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have one classifier (I train once) and then make several hundred thousand predictions, one for each permutation.

Comment: @andbeonetraveler then `multiprocessing` might be a viable approach. There will be some overhead, though, of all inter-process communication

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah I need to parallelize this. I had taken a look at the multiprocessing module but I'm rather lost. Can you point me to a tutorial? What kind of container would be best to intitalize--a list, pandas dataframe, or something else?

Answer (score -1):

The `append` operation in pandas and `for` loop are slow. This code avoids using it.

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

combos = itertools.permutations('abcdefghi',2)
combo_values = [('-'.join(x[1]), x[0]) for x in enumerate(combos, 1)]

rdf = pd.DataFrame({'combos': [x[0] for x in combo_values],
                    'value': [x[1] for x in combo_values]})
```

You can do this for each file and dataframe that you have then use [pd.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) to quickly generate results thereafter. You can also add the enumeration of the permutations afterward if you want.

Comment: They don't `append` to a dataframe.... The dataframe constructor is called after the list is complete.

Comment: They don't use `.append` on the data-frame. You are still using a "for loop", it's just a list comprehension now. While this might be marginally faster, it isn't really a solution, since almost certainly, the bottleneck is not actually building the list.

Comment: The minimum working code does not need the append. This solution works and does not need append operation.

Comment: @kevins_1 yes, but it offers no significant advantage. If anything, yours is slower because of the way you are initializing your data-frame, but all of this is pretty irrelevant.

Comment: The advantage is significant and shows that the operation listed above for 1) is a good start. It is also faster than 'apply': https://tomaugspurger.github.io/modern-4-performance

Comment: The advantage is not significant at all. In any event, you haven't even bothered to profile it. What does this have to do with `.apply`? You seem to be thoroughly confused. What in that link do you think is relevant to your answer?

Comment: Where does the OP call _apply_? Whatever you've taken away from that article, I'm pretty sure you've got some concepts confused.

Comment: As OP's question states _apply_ is mentione in 2) above. Here is a reference for how a list comprehension is faster than an append. I'd expect cython and parallelizing are also viable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108488/are-list-comprehensions-and-functional-functions-faster-than-for-loops

Comment: @kevins_1 list comprehensions are *marginally* faster than append, and in this case, would make no appreciable difference. From your link: "A list comprehension is usually a tiny bit faster than the precisely equivalent for loop "